# What is the purpose of M.2 key M config pins?

Tags: pci-express, m.2

I am designing a device that shall use PE on the PC via M.2 key M socket, and I cannot find info about how to connect it properly. In [different sources](https://pinoutguide.com/HD/M.2_NGFF_connector_pinout.shtml) I see [different info](https://www.anandtech.com/show/13609/pcisig-warns-of-incompatibilities-between-m2-and-samsungs-ngsff) regarding M.2 config pins (1, 21, 69 and 75). I found some docs over internet, and according to these docs, these pins are:

- Pin 1.  Config 3
- Pin 21. Config 0
- Pin 69. Config 1
- Pin 75. Config 2

As I understand, the purpose of these pins is to configure each lane to either PE or SATA mode, i. e. grounded pin means that appropriate lane shall be in SATA mode, and not connected pin means the corresponding lane is PE. Is it correct? As I don't use sata and want to use only one (first) PE lane, do I need to leave all these pins not connected? Also, as most mobos I've seen have just one SATA connected to the M.2, do I understand correctly, that only pin 21 is relevant?

Or, to ask more general question: What is the purpose of these pins and shall I leave these pins unconnected in order to use the socket lanes as PE, not SATA?

Comment: *Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design.* - if you don't think that computer PC hardware applies to this clause then do explain. Then, if you don't think it applies, you should add links to where this data is stated.

Comment: I am designing m.2 device and need to know how to connect it properly. It is mine device that i need to design

Comment: @Andyaka i've changed my question to make it clear, is it ok now?

Comment: You have no links to anything you talk about regards what you have seen: *In different sources I see different info regarding M.2 config pins (1, 21, 69 and 75). I found some docs over internet* - how can anyone help without visibility of what you have seen and what you might be referring to?

Comment: @Andyaka i simply googled it, this is actually my question - to understand how shall I connect my device to the m.2 slot. Added 2 links.

Comment: You should try and find a bona fide M.2 sata standard.

Comment: But I don’t need sata, i need pe, that’s what my question about

Comment: Good luck, hope someone can help.

Comment: I hope too, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Config_X pins are set by the device in order to signal to the host what type of device it is. The full table is [located here](https://pinoutguide.com/HD/M.2_NGFF_connector_pinout.shtml).

This applies to M-Key and B-Key style sockets.

For SSD SATA/PCIe devices, the Config_X pins would be:

| Config_0 | Config_1 | Config_2 | Config_3 | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pin 21 | pin 69 | pin 75 | pin 1 |  |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | SSD-SATA |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | SSD-PCIe |

According to the M.2 Spec, the host is responsible for providing pull-up resistors on these pins.  The device either grounds the pin to signal 0 (low) or leaves it not connected to signal 1 (high).

It appears that the host can choose what voltage to connect the pull-ups to since it seems the intent is to generally hardwire the configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please clarify this: “The device either grounds the pin or leaves it not connected to signal a 0 or 1, respectively.”. Does it mean that pulldown means 0 and floating means 1? Or pull down AND floating means 0 but pullup means 1?

Comment: Good feedback.  I updated that section for more clarity.